# Share stock multi-shop prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7, multisite, stock

Good, is there any option to share the stock after creating the multiTienda without losing the stock that we already have ?, I have realized that if I activate this now the stock of all products is set to 0 and I can not do that because I have more than 5000 products. I have thought about modifying something of the programming to solve it, but if there is some way to do it without having to modify the programming, some module or whatever it would be milk. Otherwise, if it ever happened to you, how did you solve it? If it was done with programming, what did you do?

Beforehand

Thank you very much, and go brown ... xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, export the _PREFIX_stock_available table, and once you've done the sharing, re-import it.

Regards,